# Transition CSS "transform" attribute

Tags: html, css, sass

How do I style the below attribute transform so that instead of becoming:

```
transform="translate(0,250)"
```

it becomes:

```
transform="translate(-45,250)"
```

so that it shifts the whole object -45 pixels to the left.

Below is the code:

```
<svg width="365" height="250">
<g class="x_ticks_d3 plain" transform="translate(0,250)"></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: What do you mean by styling an attribute? Sorry but I just don't get it.

Comment: I want to set the transform="translate(-45,250)" instead of it is now 
transform="translate(0,250)". I want to select .x_ticks_d3 transform{attribute(-45,250)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we talk about "styling" you can do sth. like this with CSS:

```
g.x_ticks_d3.plain {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-45px);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-45px);
    -o-transform: translateX(-45px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-45px);
    transform: translateX(-45px);
}
```

But this is NOT changing the svg translation and furthermore the 250 in your svg might not always match pixels (remember the scalable vector thing).

The more promising way is manipulating the attribute using jQuery:

```
$("g").attr("transform", "translate(-45,250)");
```

Comment: Thanks alot, you made my day, had so much trouble dealing with this in coffe script.